# Translating geoTiff file from 0 360 longitude to -180 to 180 degrees longitude command line

Tags: gdal, geotiff, map-projections

I have a GeoTiff file that starts and ends at the prime meridion basically with longitudes going from 0 to 360 degrees. How do I translate the longitudes of this file using a command line command so that the map starts and ends at the international dateline instead?

I tried using the following commands but with no success:

```
gdal_translate -projwin 180 90 360 -90 gfs_file_windonly_ami.tiff adjust_n180_0.tiff
gdal_translate -projwin 0 90 180 -90 gfs_file_windonly_ami.tiff adjust_0_180.tiff
gdal_merge.py -o adjust_n180_0.tiff adjust_0_180.tiff final_adjust.tiff
```

The first line of code generates a geotiff extending from dateline to prime meridion, the second line of code generates a geotiff extending from prime meridion to dateline which means that the last line of code merges the above geotiff files and should generate a geotiff final_adjust.tiff that should have a -180 to 180 degree map projection. Unfortunately it does not. It is still 0 to 360.

How do I tweak the above lines of code to get the tiff to translate from 0 to 360 to -180 to 180?

Furthermore how do I generate a geotiff that goes from -180 to 180 twice essentially having longitude coordinates of -180 to 540 degrees longitude?

Comment: The `projwin` flag is for creating a subset. You probably want to use `gdal_edit` with the `a_ullr` flag. Or open the dataset in "update mode" and set the new geotransform that you want.